# mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server (without freetds.conf)

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I have 2 servers: one is OpenSUSE, another one is SLES 11 sp2 Suse Linux Enterprise Server.

In order to have connection to MSSQL I have to install mssql.so for php.

OpenSUSE permits to install mssql from rpm.
SLES - does not have mssql rpm, and this is why need to compile it.

OpenSUSE: mssql rpm installed =>

```
$server="172.x.x.x:49888";
$username="username";
$password="password";
$link = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);
```

here successfully connected to MSSQL!

SLES: with mssql.so compiled =>

```
$server="172.x.x.x:49888";
$username="username";
$password="password";
$link = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);
```

error: Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: 172.x.x.x:49888

and if I edit freetds.conf

```
#A typical Microsoft server
[Dovico]
    host = 172.x.x.x
    port = 49888
    tds version = 7.0
```

and change php like this:

```
$server="Dovico";
$username="username";
$password="password";
$link = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);
```

=> successfully connected to MSSQL!

So my question is how can I have MSSQL connection on SLES (with mssql.so compiled) using this

```
mssql_connect("172.x.x.x:49888", "username", "password");
```

and not using freetds.conf ?

Comment: take the opensuse srpm for mssql and compile it on sles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit `freetds.conf` (uncomment and change version):

from

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;   tds version = 4.2
```

to

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
    tds version = 7.0
```

and restart Apache.

Comment: Hi ihtus. If someone edits out chatty material that is not germane to a post, please leave it be. Thanks!