# Connecting mssql using php in linux server

Tags: php

When try to connect the mssql using php. i am getting below error.

```
$serverName = "17x.xx.xx.x:1433";
$conn = mssql_connect( $serverName, "xxxx","xxx");
if (!$conn || !mssql_select_db('xxxx', $conn)) {
echo "fail";
    die(print_r(mssql_get_last_message()));
}
```

Getting error

```
mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: 17x.xx.xx.x:1433
```

when i tried to connect via putty , it is connecting.

```
tsql -S 17x.xx.xx.x -p 1433  -U xxxx -P xxx

php -i | grep mssql
```

This all working, but when try by php it is not connecting, what will be issue. please help me

My php version is 5.5.29

Comment: Can you show us the `mssql_connect()` line?

Comment: $serverName = "17x.xx.xx.x:1433";
$conn = mssql_connect( $serverName, "xxxx","xxx");
if (!$conn || !mssql_select_db('xxxx', $conn)) {
echo "fail";
    die(print_r(mssql_get_last_message()));
}

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180746/mssql-connect-unable-to-connect-to-server-without-freetds-conf ?